# How to play .mp4 video in MPMoviePlayer controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Kindly tell me how to play a .mp4 format video play in MPMoviePlayerController

```
    NSString *urlStr=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Tour.mp4" ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,154,720,428);
    [moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: NSString *urlStr=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Tour" ofType:mp4];

Answer (score 0):

Add MediaPlayer Framework

import it to your file

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

Create an object of MPMoviePlayerController

```
MPMoviePlayerController * moviePlayer;

write this code where you wants to play video    

NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test.mp4" ofType:nil];  
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];   
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];  
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];      
moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;   
[moviePlayer play];
```

try above code...

Comment: It's always good to say what they were doing wrong and what you did to fix the issue instead of just posting code and saying **try above code...** So please can you provide more detail to your answer